# Keyboard command to get out of auto generated double quotes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml, editor

I have a real simple and seemingly stupid question, but I am getting alittle frusterated.  I really like the intellesence in Visual Studio 2008, but there is one thing that is bothering me.  When I am writing some XAML, and the intellesence comes up, I select the appropriate property and it automatically inserts it along with the nessesaty ="" and then puts the cursor in between the double quotes.  When I type in the value I want, I don't know how to jump out of the double quotes.  I can use the arrow key or the mouse, but that requires leaving the home row, and I don't want to do that.  Anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for asking this. Was starting to piss me off >.>

Answer (score 5):

Try using Ctrl+U

This shortcut would replace and lowercase whatever letter after the cursor.

Using this shortcut on a symbol would replace it with the same symbol.

Your hands won't leave the home row keys and your cursor would be placed after the ending quotation mark.

Comment: Lifesaver!!! I can't believe that VS doesn't recognize when you type a final quote " and move you out of the quotes. ctrl+u works great (tested in VS2015).

Answer (score 4):

You could bind IDE command `Edit.WordNext` to the keyboard combination which comfortable for you. Say you could bind it to `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\`.