# How to exit a closing quotation mark

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

After typing `ScaleX=` the cursor moves to the inside of two quotation marks. After typing whatever is needed inside them - how do I exit the closing quotation mark without having to click on the right-arrow button (which is more cumbersome than using Enter or Tab or just typing a quotation mark, which I expected to work)?

Comment: What about the 'escape' key? Or try keying the closing quotation mark anyway. Some editors are smart enough to know you don't intend to have double quotation marks, and treats that action the same as moving the cursor one character to the right.

Comment: @BenHarrison I did try typing a quotation mark which surprisingly did not work. Haven't tried ESC yet... Nope. Doesn't work either.

Comment: I'd leave a comment on the VS team blog. This gets endlessly on my nerves too. It's as bad as the extra commas, equals signs, and curly braces in markup extensions. Maybe it's time for me to leave them another demented rant.

Comment: I think if you wanted you can just turn that self closing tag stuff off if it makes it easier via the options, or resharper does it too if I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard command to get out of auto generated double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125929/keyboard-command-to-get-out-of-auto-generated-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

**There are settings that help you in Disabling these options for Visual Studio.**

For Xaml

1) Go to Tools -> Options

2) Click on `Show All Settings` if it is unchecked.

3) Under Text `Editor Navigate` to `XAML`

4) Under Miscellaneous, Turn On/Off the options.

This is a screenshot of my Settings.

[image]